# Receber um json como parâmetro Java Servlet

Tags: java, json, web-service, java-ee, servlet

Estou desenvolvendo uma **API** usando **java servlet**, gostaria de saber como faço para receber um **JSON** no corpo da requisição como parâmetro e gravar em um banco de dados?

Exemplo:

```
{
    "nome": "José da Silva",
    "email": "jose@teste.com.br",
    "telefone": "(21) 99999-99099",
    "ativo": true,
    "empresa": {
      "nome": "Empresa Teste 1",
      "endereco": "Avenida das Américas",
      "site": "www.exemplo.com.br",
      "email": "empresa1@teste.com.br"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Você pode postar o que já fez até agora relativo ao envio e recebimento da requisição?

Comment: Eu ainda não fiz nada, procurei alguns exemplos mas não encontrei nenhum exemplos.